Designing a 0.18-µm CMOS Multi-Stage MOSFET Amplifier (150 V/V Gain, 1-5 GHz) Without External Resistors/Capacitors
I'm working on a project to design a full-transistor-based (MOSFET) multi-stage amplifier using 0.18-µm CMOS technology. The requirements for the amplifier are as follows:

Voltage gain of at least 150 V/V
Input resistance less than 1 kilo ohm
Upper 3-dB frequency (fH) between 1 GHz and 5 GHz
The main amplifier circuit should use no more than three MOSFETs
The design must not use any external resistors or capacitors;
it has to be completely MOSFET-based

I am considering using a cascode amplifier consisting of a common-gate (CG) and common-source (CS) configuration with a cascode current source. However, I am struggling with achieving the low input impedance of less than 1 kilo ohm. Additionally, I am concerned about constructing the entire amplifier without using any external resistors or capacitors.
To meet the upper 3dB frequency requirement, I reckon I can try varying the parasitic internal capacitance values of the transistors.
I am completely new to amplifier design and I understand that I might be missing some fundamental concepts. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or tips on how to approach this design. If anyone can refer to some relevant learning materials, I would be more than happy to go through them. Currently, my main learning source is Sedra/Smith's Microelectronic Circuits book, but I fear it doesn't delve deeply into practical design aspects and focuses more on theoretical concepts.
I have added the specifications for the 0.18 µm CMOS technology I am using in the picture.


I don't understand. Is there any linearity specification to this LNA? Most RF LNA use some sort of feedback, so integrated passives are always used. What is your maximum input signal and why the need for a low input impedance? are you driving it from a high-impedance source, perhaps something with a current source character?

@Designalog
No specific linearity requirement is given, but I aim to maintain a reasonably linear response for signal integrity.
Without external resistors or capacitors, how can I implement effective feedback using MOSFETs only? I'm considering using MOSFETs in the triode region to mimic resistive behavior. Any examples or references would be helpful.
The maximum input signal is around 0.01 V peak-to-peak. I am unsure about the low input impedance (<1 kΩ) requirement as my lecturer didn't provide further details.

what load are you supposed to be driving?

A current source load. So basically, i want to use a MOSFET based current source load and I want to use a MOSFET based current source driver as well. I guess that's the reason for the low impedance?
